# disturbance / passive or action

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I just wrote this:

> In addition, **I have been learned** concerning microbial toxins by Microbiology course. At the same time, Physiology and Biochemistry courses helped me to understand how toxins could **cause disturbance in normal cellular functionings**

1. In the first sentence, I've used passive form. Is this correct or should I change it to "I have learned"?
2. Do you think "cause disturbance in normal cellular functionings" sounds natural or I should change it?

Comment: Your use of *learned* is questionable. Also, you may find [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"In addition,I have been learned concerning microbial toxins by Microbiology course. At the same time, Physiology and Biochemistry courses helped me to understand how toxins could cause disturbance in normal cellular functionings" khashayer

" Studying Physiology, Microbiology and Biochemistry, I now have knowleadge of the 
 damage toxins have on normal cellular activity."

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it:

In addition, I am learned in matters concerning microbial toxins, thanks to my Microbiology course. At the same time, Physiology and Biochemistry courses helped me to understand how toxins could cause disturbances in normal cellular functions.

Bear in mind that I am by no means an expert.

Comment: Does "I am learned in matters concerning...." not sound pompous and arrogant? "I have been taught about..." or "I learned about..." would be more humble (and so more acceptable to me).